# Making a table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I am having this issue where the table is not being displayed with my Javascript.  It is suppose to work to where once the user enters the 10 numbers in the `window.prompt` the numbers would be put into an array and displayed into a table.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<script type = "text/javascript">

var number = -99;
var array1 = new Array(10);

number = window.prompt("Enter 1 to continue \n Enter -99 to exit");
if(number == -99 || number == ""){
    exit();
}else
    array1 = window.prompt("Please enter 10 numbers to be stored into an array");

    function outputArray(heading, theArray, output){
    var content = "<h2>" + heading + "</h2><table><thead><th>Index</th><th>Value</th></thead><tbody>";
    var length = theArray.length;
    for(var i=0; i<length;++i){
    content += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + theArray[i] + "</td></tr>";
    }
    content += "</tbody></table>";
    output.innerHTML = content;
    }

    outputArray("Your Array is:", array1, document.getElementById("output"));
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your script in a onload handler:

```
var onLoadHandler = function() {
    var number = -99;
    var array1 = new Array(10);

    number = window.prompt("Enter 1 to continue \n Enter -99 to exit");
    if(number == -99 || number == ""){
        exit();
    }else
        array1 = window.prompt("Please enter 10 numbers to be stored into an array");

        function outputArray(heading, theArray, output){
            var content = "<h2>" + heading + "</h2><table><thead><th>Index</th><th>Value</th></thead><tbody>";
            var length = theArray.length;
            for(var i=0; i<length;++i){
            content += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + theArray[i] + "</td></tr>";
            }
            content += "</tbody></table>";
            output.innerHTML = content;
        }

        outputArray("Your Array is:", array1, document.getElementById("output"));
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', onLoadHandler, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', onLoadHandler );
}
```

I.e. you are trying to manipulate a DOM element, which may be still not there.

Comment: That works perfect. I need to do some research on these window.addEventListener and attachevent.  Any recommendations for a good tutorial?  And Thank you very much.